# Looking for a formula to calculate the resitance needed to make a proximity sensor shorter! RCWL-0516

Tags: pcb, resistors, resistance, formula-derivation

I want to  decrease the range of this cheap sensor dramatically from 5m to 5cm! Im not sure which equation I use to calculate this. I'm assuming but not sure if there is a bigger resister value that I can place here to get this effect!

This is the part that I'm refereeing to!

> R-GN: Detection distance adjustment (default 7 m). Adding a resistor
> the detection distance will become shorter. If connected with a 1-MΩ
> resistor, detection range is about 5 m.

[image]

Comment: wouldn't count on it

Comment: Have you read this ? https://www.rogerclark.net/investigating-a-rcwl-9196-rcwl-0516-radar-motion-detector-modules/

Comment: No ouu thank you!